# Обращение к динамически сгенерированному свойству класса

Tags: php

Пусть есть класс, реализующий мультиязычный интерфейс:

```
class Menu {
  static $ru_menu = array{
                    "title"=>'главная',
                    "description"=>'тра-ля-ля...'
                  }
  static $en_menu = array{
                    "title"=>'main',
                    "description"=>'bla-bla-bla...'
                  }
}
```

Переменная  $_SESSION['lang'] содержит одно из значений - "ru" или "en". Как, исходя из этой переменной, обратиться к соответствующему значению массива без использования eval()?

В общем, хотелось бы как-то так (псевдокод):

```
$prop = $_SESSION['lang']."_menu";
Menu:: ${$prop}['title'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Menu {

    static $languages = array(
        'ru_menu' => array(
            "title"       => 'главная',
            "description" => 'тра-ля-ля...'
        ),
        'en_menu' => array(
            "title"       => 'main',
            "description" => 'bla-bla-bla...'
        )
    );
}

$lang = "ru_menu";

echo Menu::$languages[$lang]['title'];
```

Comment: не а, свойство $language неопредело...

Comment: у класса Menu НЕТ СВОЙСТВА $language! \$$language тоже не помогает

Comment: Тогда имеет смысл немного переделать класс, как я указал в ответе.

Comment: )) Подождем еще немного. Почти так я и делал изначально. Интересна реализация косвенной адресации как указано в вопросе.